# Changing an array in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, parsing

I am trying to use Perl to parse output from a (C-based) program.
Every output line is a (1D) Perl array, which I sometimes want to store (based on certain conditions).

I now wish to (deep) *copy* an array when its first element has a certain keyword,
and print that same copied array if another keyword matches in a later line-array.

So far, I have attempted the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict; # recommended
use Storable qw(dclone);
...
while(1)   # loop over the lines
    {
        # subsequent calls to tbse_line contain
        # (references to) arrays of data 
        my $la = $population->tbse_line();
        my @copy;
        my $header = shift @$la;

        # break out of the loop:
        last if ($header eq 'fin');

        if($header eq 'keyword')
        {
            @copy = @{ dclone \@$la };
        }

        if($header eq 'other_keyword')
        {
            print "second condition met, print first line:\n"
            print "@copy\n";
        }
    }
```

However, this prints an empty line to the screen, instead of the contents of the copied array. I don't have a lot of Perl experience, and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Any idea on how to go about this?

Comment: We don't know what ->tbse_line() returns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`my @copy` allocates a new Perl array named `@copy` in the current scope. It looks like you want to set `@copy` during one iteration of your `while` loop and print it in a different iteration. In order for your array not to be erased each time a new `while` loop iteration starts, you should move the `my @copy` declaration outside of the loop.

```
my @copy;
while (1) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the issue! The code above is just a small part of a very large code that I did not write myself, but am trying to adapt to my current processing needs. I must have overlooked the positioning of the array declaration.

Comment: You should [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it's solved your problem :)